# Showing that decay results of Fourier coefficients are sharp

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I originally post the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4783208) but the it seems too advanced for undergraduate level. At least, an example is very hard to find, so I am putting it here.

It is well-known that if $f$ is absolutely continuous and $2\pi$-periodic, then the Fourier coefficients will have rate of decay $o(|k|^{-1}).$

How can I find an example which gets arbitrarily close to this bound? That is, given any function $\lambda(k) = o(|k|^{-1})$ can I find a function $f$ such that the fourier coefficients of $f$ decays slower than the sequence $\lambda(k)$? I have tried examples like the triangle wave; all of them decay at rate $O(|k|^{-2}),$ and are not very helpful.

Any **partial** example (like $O(|k|^{-1+\epsilon})$) is welcome - if a full solution is too hard.

Comment: for example $g(x)=\sum_{n \ge 2} \cos nx /\log n$ is a Fourier series so in particular $g$ is integrable, hence $\sum_{n \ge 2} \sin nx /(n \log n)$ is absolutely continuous with derivative $g$ ae and has coefficients $1/(n \log n)$; similarly one can construct a Fourier (cosine) series with coefficients $a_k$ at least $|\epsilon(k)|$ for any $\epsilon(k) \to 0$ by finding a convex decreasing to zero $a_k \ge |\epsilon (k)|$ and considering $\sum a_k \cos kx$ which again is a Fourier series so integrable; and then integrating this with $\epsilon (k) =\lambda (k)/k$ works

Comment: @Conrad Many thanks for your answer. But why is an a.e. convergent Fourier series guaranteed to be integrable?

Comment: not in general (see $\sum \sin nx/ \log n$ which is actually convergent everywhere to a function continuous  except at $0$ but one which is not integrable Lebesgue)  but if $a_n$ is convex and decreasing to zero then the cosine trigonometric series is integrable, so is a Fourier series- this is seen summing by parts twice and using that $a_n$ convex implies $a_n -a_{n-1}$ monotonically decreases to zero so $n(a_n-a_{n-1}) \to 0$

Comment: @Conrad Wow. So how can we prove that?

Comment: @MaJoad: Convergence really has very little to do with it (= the question of whether a given sequence is the FT of an $L^1$ function). There are also $L^1$ functions with everywhere divergent Fourier series.

Comment: this is standard (see Zygmund or Katznelson); in brief one shows by double partial summation that if $s_n = a_0/2+\sum_{1 \le k \le n}a_n \cos nx$ then $s_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(n+1)\Delta^2a_k K_k(x)+nK_{n-1}(x)\Delta a_{n-1}+D_n(x)a_n$ where $\Delta^2 a_k= a_k-2a_{k+1}+a_{k+2} \ge 0$ by convexity, $K_n, D_n$ are Feijer and Dirichlet kernels; since $\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(n+1)\Delta^2 a_k$ converges (and is non negative) by the above, $s_n$ converges except possibly at $0$ and is integrable since $K_k \ge 0$ and we can integrate term by term by the monotone convergence theorem

Comment: @MaJoad, yes, following up on Christian Remling's comment, Kolmogorov found an  $L^1$ functions with Fourier series that diverged _everywhere_. It's not a simple story, and I myself have not understood it. :)

Comment: @Christian - there is a (deep) theorem that says that if a trigonometric series $\sum (a_n \cos nx+b_n \sin nx)$ converges (everywhere) to an integrable function, it is a Fourier series - above we see a trigonometric series that converges everywhere but it is not a Fourier series as the limit function is not integrable; a somewhat less deep but still nontrivial theorem says that if a trigonometric series converges to zero except at countably many points, it is the zero series, while there are examples of trigonometric series converging to zero ae without being identically zero

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for the reference. Indeed, this seems to be very specific and not many people know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an elementary solution:

For $a\in(0,\pi)$ and $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$, let
\begin{equation*}
    g_a(x):=\frac1a\,g\Big(\frac xa\Big)-\frac1{2\pi}
    =\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_{an}\cos nx, \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
where $g(u):=\max(0,1-|u|)$ and
\begin{equation*}
    c_t:=\frac{1-\cos t}{\pi t^2/2}
\end{equation*}
for real $t\ne0$.
(The latter equality in \eqref{1} follows by (say) the [Dirichlet–Jordan test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%E2%80%93Jordan_test#Dirichlet%E2%80%93Jordan_test_for_Fourier_series).)
Note that $\int_{-\pi}^\pi |g_a|=\int_{-\pi}^\pi |g_1|<\infty$ and $\int_{-\pi}^\pi g_a=0=\int_0^\pi g_a$.

Let
\begin{equation*}
    G:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k g_{1/k}, \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation}
\text{$p_k>0$ for all $k\quad$ and $\quad\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k<\infty$. }   \tag{2.5}\label{2.5}
\end{equation}
Then $G\in L^1[-\pi,\pi]$ and $\int_{-\pi}^\pi G=0$.

For $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$, let
\begin{equation*}
    f(x):=\int_0^x du\,G(u), \tag{3}\label{3} 
\end{equation*}
with $\int_0^x:=-\int_x^0$ for $x\in[-\pi,0)$. Then $f$ can be extended to an absolutely continuous $2\pi$-periodic function.
Moreover, then for $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\sin nx 
\end{equation*}
(again by the Dirichlet–Jordan test)
and for the $n$th sine Fourier coefficient $b_n$ of $f$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    b_n=\frac1n\,\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k c_{n/k}
    \ge\frac1n\,\sum_{k=n}^\infty p_k c_{n/k}
    \ge\frac Cn\,\sum_{k=n}^\infty p_k \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{equation*}
for some real $C>0$ and all natural $n$. (The first equality in \eqref{4} follows, informally, from \eqref{3} by integrating the series expression of $G$ in \eqref{2} and the series expression of $g_a(x)$ in \eqref{1} termwise. Rigorously, the first equality in \eqref{4} follows from \eqref{3}, \eqref{2}, the definition of $g_a(x)$ in \eqref{1}, and the Fubini theorem -- see details on this at the end of the answer.)

Since $\sum_{k=n}^\infty p_k$ may converge to $0$ however slowly (as $n\to\infty$), we see from \eqref{4} that the rate of decay of the $b_n$'s can be however close to that of $\frac1n$. $\quad\Box$

**Details on the first equality in \eqref{4}:** For all natural $n$,
\begin{align*}
    b_n&=\frac2\pi\,\int_0^\pi dx\,\sin nx\,f(x) \\ 
    &=\frac2\pi\,\int_0^\pi dx\,\sin nx\,\int_0^x du\,G(u) \\ 
    &=\frac2\pi\,\int_0^\pi du\,G(u)\,\int_u^\pi dx\,\sin nx \\ 
    &=\frac2{\pi n}\,\int_0^\pi du\,G(u)\,(\cos nu-\cos n\pi)  \\ 
    &=\frac2{\pi n}\,\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k\int_0^\pi du\,g_{1/k}(u)\,(\cos nu-\cos n\pi) \\ 
    &=\frac2{\pi n}\,\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k\int_0^\pi du\,g_{1/k}(u)\,\cos nu  \\ 
    &=\frac1n\,\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k c_{n/k}.  
\end{align*}

Comment: Great answer! Many thanks.